# List all Java repositories on github using api

Tags: curl, github, github-api

I am trying to get a list of all github repositories for a specific language (e.g. Java), without narrowing the search by any specific keyword. Preferably, I want to do this directly from curl, no scripting. The problem is that I've tried formatting the API URL and didn't manage to find the right one, that includes the `language=Java` parameter but no keyword.

For example, the following URL seems to query for repos with the keywords "language" or "java" in their description, including some Scala and Haskell repos:

```
 curl -X GET https://api.github.com/legacy/repos/search/language=java
```

On the other hand, using the `?` notation returns empty results:

```
 curl -X GET https://api.github.com/legacy/repos/search?language=java
 curl -X GET https://api.github.com/legacy/repos/search/?language=java
```

Lower- or upper-case J also seems irrelevant.

So how do I use the language parameter without specifying a keyword?

**Comment**: A trick that seems to work is to use a single-letter keyword, repeating from A to Z. Is there a less awkward way?

Comment: Yeah, it seems that the only way to do it is the single-letter keyword trick. Interesting how even their webapp search doesn't allow you do search for all Java (or any other lang) repositories without specifying a keyword -- https://github.com/search. They must have done this on purpose, for whatever reason.

Comment: did you find any good way to do this?

Answer (score 6):

I would use this according to the v3 api: 
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:Java

In case you want to sort:

https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:Java&sort=stars&order=desc

Answer (score 3):

You were close to the answer. In order to get results for a specific language you have to use the colon, like this:

```
language:{your_language_here}
```

So for Java it would be:

```
curl -X GET https://api.github.com/legacy/repos/search/language:java
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the main search form on the github site to do this.  But make sure you use the "language:NAME" syntax in your query and not use the dropdown list of languages.

For example:
https://github.com/search?q=language%3AJava&type=Repositories

Not as easy to parse as the JSON from the API but should do the job.