# Most "popular" Python repos on GitHub

Tags: json, curl, github, github-api

Based on the [v3 documentation](http://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-repositories) I would have thought that this:

```
$ curl https://api.github.com/legacy/repos/search/python?language=Python&sort=forks&order=desc
```

would return the top 100 Python repositories in descending order of number of forks. It actually returns an empty (json) list of repositories.

This:

```
$ curl https://api.github.com/legacy/repos/search/python?language=Python&sort=forks
```

returns a list of repositories (in json), but many of them are not listed as Python repositories.

So, clearly I have misunderstood the Github API. What is the accepted way of retrieving the top *N* repositories for a particular language?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12882049/list-all-java-repositories-on-github-using-api?rq=1

Comment: That curl -X use is completely wrong. -X takes a following keyword, but note that -X is mostly used wrong: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/faq.html#curl_X_gives_me_HTTP_problems

Comment: Thanks, I've removed that now. In reality I was using the Python bindings to curl, but the details of the script were irrelevant to the question, but thanks for the info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pengwynn said -- currently this is not easily doable via GitHub's API alone. However, have a look at this alternative way of querying using the GitHub Archive project: [How to find the 100 largest GitHub repositories for a past date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13745285/how-to-find-the-100-largest-github-repositories-for-a-past-date)

In essence, you can query GitHub's historical data using an SQL-like language. So, if having real-time results is not something that is important for you, you could execute the following query on https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/?pli=1 to get the top 100 Python repos as on April 1st 2013 (yesterday), descending by the number of forks:

```
SELECT MAX(repository_forks) as forks, repository_url 
 FROM [githubarchive:github.timeline] 
 WHERE (created_at CONTAINS "2013-04-01" and repository_language = "Python") 
 GROUP BY repository_url 
 ORDER BY forks 
 DESC LIMIT 100
```

I've put the results of the query in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/izuzak/0192f6576532594e1365) in CSV format, and the top few repos are:

```
forks  repository_url
1913   https://github.com/django/django
1100   https://github.com/facebook/tornado
994    https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask
...
```

Comment: Thanks, that's incredibly useful!

Answer (score 3):

The intent of Repository Search API is to find Repositories by keyword and then further filter those results by the other optional query string parameters.

Since you're missing a `?`, you're passing the entire intended query string as the `:keyword`. I'm sorry, we do not support your intended search via the GitHub API at this time.

Comment: Thanks. I've added a keyword now and a `?`. If this query is not supported does that mean that the API documentation is wrong or have I just misunderstood it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:Python&sort=forks&order=desc

It is searching over repositories.